# iOS scrolling background placement issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a little issue i'm trying to figure out. I want to scroll a background image from top to bottom, but it just won't go the right way. Here's what I got so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode * bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    bg.position = CGPointMake(0, bg.size.height * i);
    bg.name = @"bg";
    [_bgLayer addChild:bg];
}
```

The image shows up about 2/3 to the left on the simulator and the right side of the screen is just black. Now doesn't bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero; move the reference point from center to bottom left? If I get rid of that line and do self.frame.size.width / 2, it centers it. Also the height and width of my *bg are only showing 768 and the Background image is 864x1536 which is another thing that doesn't make sense. Anyone see the problem?

Comment: Well, I figured out a part of my issue. xCode SpriteKit template creates the MyScene.sks which has the size set as 1024 x 768 hence my problem with the height maxing out at 768. Why would it have a defined size and not go based on device?

Comment: Not sure what the deal is, but I got it working(at least for now) by changing scaleMode to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill. All other modes really distort or misplace the image.